# Delete Scale for Height in dendrogram visualisation

Tags: r, visualization, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, dendextend

I can create  a dendrogram using

```
x<-1:100
dim(x)<-c(10,10)
set.seed(1)
groups<-c("red","red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue","blue", "red", "blue")
x.clust<-as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(x)))

x.clust.dend <- x.clust
labels_colors(x.clust.dend) <- groups
x.clust.dend <- assign_values_to_leaves_edgePar(x.clust.dend, value = groups, edgePar = "col") # add the colors.
x.clust.dend <- assign_values_to_leaves_edgePar(x.clust.dend, value = 3, edgePar = "lwd") # make the lines thick
plot(x.clust.dend)
```

However I want to delete the scale of height information in the left as shown in Figure below. [image]
My guess is that it should be extremely trivial but I am not able to find a way to do this. One solution which I don't want is using the `ggplot2` as below:

```
ggplot(as.ggdend(dend2))
```

This is because I will loose some of the formatting like `color_bars()`

Comment: try this: plot(x.clust.dend, yaxt="n")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The graphical parameter 'axes = FALSE" can be used to remove the distance measure for the plot.dendogram command:

```
plot(x.clust.dend, axes=F)
```

This will produce the following dendogram without distance axis:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can just set `yaxt = "n"`

```
plot(x.clust.dend, yaxt = "n")
```

You can add another axis with

```
axis(side = 2, labels = FALSE)
```